# Write the equation of the lowest degree with real coefficients if two of its roots are $-1$ and $1+i$. Please explain the ansnwer.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Write the equation of the lowest degree with real coefficients if two of its roots are $-1$ and $1+i$. Please explain, as I am lost.

Comment: the other root must be $$1-i$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner would you mind explaining how you arrived to that answer? You are correct, but I am a bit confused on how I find that answer.

Comment: since the coefficients must be real

Comment: $$(x+1)(1-1-i)(x-1+i)$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Is it me or you have a typo on the polynomial you give as an answer?

Comment: yeah it must be $$(x+1)(x-1-i)(x-1+i)$$ as you stated, sorry

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Thanks you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complex roots occur in conjugate, in case of the coefficient of the  polynomial are real, so if $1+i$ is a root, the other root must be $1-i$.

you can see the link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate_root_theorem

So the required polynomial is as stated by Dr. Sonnhard Graubner.